# Which SFF work first used Pyramids?

Tags: history-of

We see Pyramids in the SFF works all the time. Few examples in my head right now:

- X-Men: Apocalypse (2016)
- The Mummy (1999)

Which SFF work first used Pyramid?

**Note:** Here, I am not talking about the mathematical structure Pyramid (Luxor Hotel won’t be counted). I am talking about Egyptian Pharaoh’s tombs. I am okay with a fictional Pyramid which they buried in the story.

Comment: I'm not sure that either X-Men or The Mummy count as sci-fi. Are you looking for just films? Also what could you mean by "used Pyramid"?

Comment: @JiminyCricket. - X-Men is definitely Sci-fi. The Mummy is Fantasy. Both fall into the category of SFF (e.g. Science Fiction &/or Fantasy)

Comment: IMHO the best modern example of sci fi related to the actual pyramids has to be *Stargate*.

Comment: If you're not talking about pyramid-shaped buildings in general (so Luxor Hotel doesn't count), can you elaborate on what you mean by "I am okay with a fictional Pyramid which they buried in the story"? Do you mean a fictional buried Ancient Egyptian pyramid, or can it be some other type of fictional pyramid built by a real ancient society like a Mayan one, or could it be an ancient buried pyramid built by Atlanteans or aliens etc.?

Comment: @Hypnosifl Egyptian Pharaoh’s tombs only. What I meant that they need not be real one which continue to exist. Also, Pharaohs can be fictional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The earliest I found was ["The Mummy! A Tale of the Twenty-Second Century"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1672885) by Jane Louden from 1827. You can read the summary on p. 792 of *Science-Fiction: The Early Years* on google books [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=KEZxhkG5eikC&lpg=PR22&pg=PA792#v=onepage&q&f=false), this is the part involving the Great Pyramid:

> Edric is greatly interested in the phenomenon of life. Is the soul (or
> life) simply a part of the body, or is it something separate? He and Father Morris, who unexpectedly takes a Cartesian view of the matter, argue the point and conclude that the argument can be settled only by reviving a corpse and questioning it. Dr. Entwurf, a German scientist, proposes a practical answer: Reanimate a dead person with galvanism. Edric and Entwurf fly to Egypt in Entwurf’s newly invented balloon (a rubber device the size of a bottle that is expanded by artificial air when needed) and proceed to the Great Pyramid. Finding Cheops’s mummy with no great difficulty, they set to work.

Answer (score 2):

[*Enoch The Philistine: A Traditional Romance of Philistia, Egypt and the Great Pyramid*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2005272) (**1898**) by Le Roy Hooker tells an account of a King of Egypt, converted to follow the Abrahamic god by a fictional descendent of Enoch, building a memorial according to instructions contained in the "*Roll of Enoch*":

> Make it four square, and plant it so that two of the sides shall be on the true line of the east and the west.
>
> The length of each of the four sides thereof shall be three hundred and sixty and five cubits and two palms.
>
> Thou shalt not make the sides upright. From the rock whereon it shall stand all the sides of the memorial shall incline equally, and in a straight line, the east side and the west side toward one another, and the north side and the south side toward one another.
>
> The sides will become narrower as they grow upward, and incline, until they meet in a point over the center of the four sides at the base, and the point where they meet shall be two hundred and thirty and two cubits, and one span, and half a span, above the rock.

The [Science Fiction Encyclopedia](https://sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/hooker_le_roy) describes it as:

> a Lost Race tale told in the first person by a man who experiences romance and desperation in the Middle East.

Comment: [Edison's Conquest of Mars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edison%27s_Conquest_of_Mars), also from 1898, featured a subplot in which it turned out that Martians had build the great pyramids--it was originally published serially (on Jan. 12 and Feb. 10 [according to isfdb](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?97832)) so I don't know when the first part with the pyramids was published, and I also can't find the exact date that *Enoch the Philistine* came out, so not sure which was first.